# PHP: ¿atributos o parámetros de método?

Tags: php, mvc, poo

Estoy intentando adaptar una web que ya tenía más o menos hecha de forma estructurada a POO + MVC y me ha surgido la siguiente duda:

Pongamos el caso de un modelo y un controlador de usuarios, de manera que el modelo tiene un método guardar, que hace un `INSERT` en la base de datos, y el controlador recibe los datos del usuario vía `POST` desde un formulario, instancia un objeto del modelo y se los pasa; mi duda es: ¿por qué no pasarle los datos simplemente como parámetros del método guardar -que más o menos es lo que ya venía haciendo en mi web estructurada- en vez de recurrir a definir atributos, *getters* y *setters*? Es decir:

```
class UsuariosModelo
{
    function guardar($nombre, $contrasena)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES (NULL, $nombre, $contrasena)";

        etc.
    }
}

class UsuariosControlador
{
    function guardar()
    {
        foreach($_POST as $clave => $valor) $$clave = $valor;

        $usuario = new UsuariosModelo;

        $resultados = $usuario->guardar($nombre, $contrasena);

        etc.
    }
}
```

De la forma ortodoxa habría que definir dentro del modelo atributos tanto para el nombre como para la contraseña y sus respectivos métodos *get* (a los que habría que llamar dentro del método `guardar()` modelo) y *set* (a los que habría que llamar dentro del método `guardar()` del controlador):

```
class UsuariosModelo
{
    $nombre;
    $contrasena;
    
    function getNombre() {return $this->nombre};
    function setNombre($nombre) {$this->nombre = $nombre};

    function getContrasena() {return $this->contrasena};
    function setContrasena($contrasena) {$this->contrasena = $contrasena};

    function guardar()
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES (NULL, '{$this->getNombre()}', '{$this->getContrasena()}')";

        etc.
    }
}

class UsuariosControlador
{
    function guardar()
    {
        foreach($_POST as $clave => $valor) $$clave = $valor;

        $usuario = new UsuariosModelo;

        $usuario->setNombre($nombre);
        $usuario->setContrasena($contrasena);
        $resultados = $usuario->guardar();

        etc.
    }
}
```

Es posible que el código tenga errores, porque lo acabo de improvisar, pero espero que se entienda la duda que planteo: ¿qué problemas -en cuanto a funcionalidad, seguridad, etc.- puede suponer hacer las cosas de manera "abreviada" más allá de que no se siga a rajatabla el paradigma POO?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano por vuestras respuestas.

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista el controlador no necesita manejar tanta lógica sobre los datos que maneja el modelo. El modelo debería tener un método que valide si todos los datos fueron ingresado antes de guardar y devolver dicho resultado al controlador. Imagina el caso que tengas mas de un controlador instanciando el mismo modelo... si seguís así vas a tener código duplicado por todos lados

Comment: Ya, estoy siguiendo un ejemplo de cursillo de Udemy y lo cierto es que mi web no se adapta muy bien a él. No hago más que dar vueltas y vueltas.

Comment: No deberías dar tantas vueltas, concentrate en terminar. Te lo resumo en una frase muy trillada "_De los errores se aprende_". Una vez que lo tengas andando, si te sobre tiempo y ganas, podes focalizarte en mejorarlo (_siempre hay algo..._).

Answer (score 1):

La idea de separar con "getters y setters", además de que sea por prolijidad, es que:

1. Podés encapsular funcionalidad a la hora de setear u obtener un valor. Supongamos (por caso) tu primer ejemplo: no funcionaría, ya que el insert que estás enviando no está metiendo las comillas "" en $usuario y $password. En el setter, podrías encapsular para que se guarde como string, o incluso hacer validaciones: si viene vacío throwrear una excepción, si el nombre es inválido también, etc...
2. Tu segundo ejemplo no está del todo bien tampoco. La idea es separarlo así: poner una capa de mdelo de datos por encima de la clase que accede al motor de la base de datos. Esto te permitiría hacer un switch a otra tecnologia de una forma muy fácil.
   De hecho, tu segundo ejemplo sigue estando mal. Si querés hacerlo bien, el método "guardar" debería estar en otra clase/conjunto de clases que se llamen (ponele) mysql.
   Esa/s clase/s (que tiene todos los métodos para hacer insert, select, etc...) las podrías meter en una carpeta que se llame Driver. Crear una interfaz que se llame (ponele) IDBDriver, que implemente esos métodos.
   Y luego siempre llamás a la interfaz y la relacionás con tu modelo de datos.
   Es muy básico el ejemplo, pero tendrías algo así:

> ```
> /model
> Usuario.php - getters y setters 
> /db
>    IDriver.interface.php - metodos select, insert, etc.. como interfaz
>    /drivers
>       mysql
>          Mysql.class.php - implementa IDriver, y hace "inserts específicos" como lo pide esa tecnología.
> ```

Luego, en tu controlador, cargás los datos (en User) que siguen siendo datos, independientes de la tecnología que vayas a usar para insertar.
Y usás el driver que quieras (en este caso, mysql) para hacer el insert. Si el día de mañana decidís cambiar de driver, solamente te toca agregar el driver correspondiente (dentro de la carpeta /drivers), escribir la lógica de como se escriben los inserts en ese driver, y hacer el switch del driver en tu controlador.

```
$this->driver = new Mysql(); --> cambia a $this->driver = new Postgress();
```

El resto te asegurás que sigue funcionando del mismo modo que antes.

Esto es muy básico. Lo ideal sería que tengas un factory para crear drivers, y que las dependencias las hagas con inyección de dependencias, y todo eso. Pero puntualmente, separar la capa de datos con la capa del modelo sería eso.

Esos son 2 beneficios que se me ocurren. Además, como otros beneficios, tenés que es más prolijo, tus clases están separadas por funcionalidad, se te va a ser más fácil armar tests unitarios, vas a tener clases con menos líneas de código y te va a resultar más fácil el debug (si lo separás por capas, es más fácil ir poniendo "var_dump" en cada capa para encontrar donde está el problema).

Comment: La función que utilizaba para registrar usuarios hacía varias comprobaciones, incluyendo sentencias preparadas para evitar inyecciones de SQL; supongo que podría trasladar parte de esa funcionalidad a los setters.